# Unmovable file stops me from shrinking partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

I am trying to shrink my main NTFS partition to get some space for a Linux partition. Howver, the Disk manager tells me the following when I try to shrink:

> You cannot shrink a volume beyond the point where any unmovable files are located. See the the "defrag" event in the Application log for detailed information about the operation when it has completed.

In the Application log, I learned that it was the paging file that was the problem. I disabled paging, and tried again. Same error, but with a new file this time:

```
\System Volume Information\{7f32e9a4-7638-11ec-a230-2816aded016f}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}::$DATA
```

The Application log also suggest that I run the following command (output below):

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>fsutil volume querycluster \\?\Volume{b96c7faa-d0df-4861-8e6f-95ed36cf6a71} 0x2ecaa27
Cluster 0x0000000002ecaa27 used by ---AD \System Volume Information\{7f32e9a4-7638-11ec-a230-2816aded016f}{3808876b-c176-4e48-b7ae-04046e6cc752}::$DATA
```

What is this unmovable file? And is there any way I can shrink my partition?

Comment: It's  System Volume Information in other words what is used to keep track of file versions.

Comment: Boot from a Windows PE disk or other windows bootable disk and run a defrag on the windows partition, this will allow moving "unmovable" files offline, then you should be able to shrink it after booting back into windows.

Comment: Or use a tool that can perform actions outside Windows, such as AIOMEI Partition Assistant. Do note, do one operation at a time, to ensure it works. So resize, execute, resize, execute, move, execute. Don't do two or more and then execute. Seems to always fail.

Comment: Also, before **any** change to disk structure, **make and verify a disk image** (unless you don't mind reformatting it and losing all data should an error occur).

Answer (score -1):

Backup your data. Put [GParted](https://gparted.org/) on a USB drive and boot from that. Then resize your partitions.  It will warn you that you could lose data, but go ahead.  It will move all the files it needs to.

Defragging isn't available for SSD drives, so that's not helpful.

Aomei Partition Editor is no longer free.  The demo version lets you set up the operation, but won't execute anything